# google datastore global connection

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

How would you declare a global for a datastore client?

So far, I have:

```
var (
    db     driver.Conn
    ctx    context.Context
    client datastore.Client
)
```

ignore the db. That's for my global db conn.

```
func bootstrap() {
    ctx = context.Background()
    pId := ProjectId
    var err error
    client, err = datastore.NewClient(ctx, pId)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("caught error:%v\n", err)
    }

}
```

My error is:
cannot assign *"cloud.google.com/go/datastore".Client to client (type "cloud.google.com/go/datastore".Client) in multiple assignment

Comment: https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#NewClient returns a `*Client` and an `error`.

Comment: You should also not have a global `Context`. That doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `client datastore.Client` to `client *datastore.Client`.

Your error message says it all:

```
cannot assign *"cloud.google.com/go/datastore".Client to client (type "cloud.google.com/go/datastore".Client) in multiple assignment
```

Condensing it a bit...

```
cannot assign *ds.Client to client (type ds.Client)...
  pointer ━━━━┷━━━━━━━━┙                 │       │
  plain type ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━┙
```

Note that the first type is a pointer, denoted by the `*` character and the second type is a plain type (with no asterisk).